# UseLegacyUI Setting Not Working

Tags: acumatica

I have ran a SQL script to update the UserPreferences.UseLegacyUI to 0 for all of the users in our 2018 R1 system but, the users are still getting the classic UI when they log into the system.  Any thoughts on why this might be?  We're trying to avoid every user having to change their setting in their profile.

EDIT: Users are having to switch to the modern UI every time they log in.  Is there a cookie involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an HTTP redirect set in IIS on both the web site and the web application that was causing this.  I suspect this was a hold over from the 5.3 installation but, not sure.  Removing the redirect from the web application and removing the "/main.aspx" from the web site redirect cured this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the UserPreference graph to change that value, that's how it's used in 'Main.aspx.cs'. Sometimes there's code in event handlers that needs to be executed too:

```
PX.SM.SMAccessPersonalMaint prefGraph = PX.Data.PXGraph.CreateInstance<PX.SM.SMAccessPersonalMaint>();
PX.SM.UserPreferences prefs = prefGraph.UserPrefs.SelectSingle() ?? prefGraph.UserPrefs.Insert();
prefs.UseLegacyUI = false;
prefGraph.UserPrefs.Update(prefs);
prefGraph.Persist();
```

Comment: You can use a 'customization plugin' to deploy the change to all users: https://help.acumatica.com/(W(78))/Wiki/ShowExport.aspx?PageID=c69443fe-4d32-47a9-85aa-b2882aa259ef&type=txt